# How to hide and un-hide image button(cancel button) on video view when user touches the video screen?

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener, android-videoview

I am trying to make my image button visible and invisible when user touches the video screen.(I am using video view to play video on android studio).Initially the image button is invisible but i want to make it visible if user touches the video screen and if he touches it again i want the image button to become invisible.

I used the following code but when i touch the video it says unfortunately your app stopped working and returns me back to main activity(closing player activity) !could an expert tell me how to fix this problem Thanks

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        but1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBack);
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            but1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            but1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

activity_player.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_player"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">




    <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>

    <ImageButton
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonBack"
        android:src="@drawable/donebutton_active"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:onClick="donebutton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

findViewById should be call after setContentView(R.layout.xxx) in onCreate,

like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.xx);
    but1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonBack);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply . i don't have any layout how to make one ? I am new to android programming so hope you help me add layout if that is needed to fix the problem.

Comment: maybe u can try to learn others' project first . like above .

Comment: I will try use the method described in that link for some other project but is there away to make the button visible using video view ?